# cljsjs jquery rewrite in my clojurescript app

Tags: jquery, clojurescript

My program was built such that the following line works under simple compilation (e.g. with Figwheel):

```
(-> (js/jQuery "document") (.ready #(.tooltip (js/jQuery "[data-toggle='tooltip']"))))
```

I need it to work under advanced compilation so I've installed and required cljsjs/jquery. However, I'm not sure how to rewrite the above code to utilize cljsjs. I know that `(js/jQuery.)` returns a thing, which I can then .init, but I'm really flying in the dark here. What's the equivalent cljsjs version of the working code above?

Answer (score 2):

What works as `js/jQuery "document"` in simple compilation can, after including cljsjs/jquery be done with `js/$ "document"` . For the tooltips you actually need cljsjs/bootstrap, however, after which the new line is:

```
(-> (js/$ "document") (.ready #(.tooltip (js/$ "[data-toggle='tooltip']"))))
```